# Simple Coding - Help Needed

Tags: python

> Write a program where you can enter one translation pair at a time,
>   (e.g. friend = kalyardi) and be told how many unique lines you have
>   entered. You should not count duplicates. The program should stop
>   asking for more words when you enter a blank line, and then print out
>   how many unique translations you know.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> Word: friend = kalyardi
> Word: happy = jipa-jipa
> Word: bird = jirripirdi
> Word: friend = kalyardi
> Word: 
> You know 3 unique word translation(s)!
> ```

and

```
Words: bandicoot = jarlku
Word: bandicoot = jarlku
Word: dog = jarntu
Word: dog = kuna-palya
Word: kangaroo = kanyarla
Word: cockatoo = ngaarnkamarda
Word: 
You know 5 unique word translation(s)!
```

> Sometimes a word will have multiple (or similar) translations in which
>   case, you want to count each translation separately, just by counting
>   the number of unique lines.

My Program Reads -

```
translation = input("Word: ")
count = 0
previous = []
while translation != "":
    if translation not in previous:
        count = (count - 1)
        translation = input("Word: ")
    else:
        break
print("You know", count, "unique translation(s)!")
```

When i run my program it does.

```
Word: bandicoot = jarlku
Word: bandicoot = jarlku
Word: dog = jarntu
Word: dog = kuna-palya
Word: kangaroo = kanyarla
Word: cockatoo = ngaarnkamarda
Word: 
You know -6 unique translation(s)!
```

What should i do to fix my program been stuck for ages!!!!!!!

Comment: You didn't even explain your problem. People shouldn't have to run your code.

Comment: Alright, just included it

Comment: You're not using `previous`. It's always empty. And don't you mean `(count + 1)`?

Comment: Could you give me an example on how to use previous?

Comment: Start by thinking about what it's for. Then find out how to add things  to your list

Comment: Have you been introduced to `dict`s yet?

Comment: @Ron: Then go through some Python tutorial. You can't attempt programming without learning the basics first, it just doesn't work, sorry. http://learnpythonthehardway.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
translation = input("Word: ")
count = 0
previous = []
while translation != "":
    if translation not in previous:
        count = (count - 1)
        previous.append(translation)
    translation = input("Word: ")

print("You know", count, "unique translation(s)!")
```

Answer (score 3):

```
translation = input("Word: ")
previous = []
while translation != "":
    source = translation.split()[0].strip()
    if source not in previous:
        previous.append (source)
    translation = input("Word: ")
print("You know", len(previous), "unique translation(s)!")
```

Yet another cool way to get input, suggested by Ashwini Chaudhary in comments.

```
previous = []
for translation in iter(input, ""):
    source = translation.split()[0].strip()
    if source not in previous:
        previous.append (source)
print("You know", len(previous), "unique translation(s)!")
```

**EDIT:** If the entire string has to be matched,

```
previous = []
for translation in iter(input, ""):
    if translation not in previous:
        previous.append (source)
print("You know", len(previous), "unique translation(s)!")
```

**Output**

```
~$ python3 Test.py 
Word: friend = kalyardi
Word: happy = jipa-jipa
Word: bird = jirripirdi
Word: friend = kalyardi
Word: 
You know 3 unique translation(s)!
```

Comment: The `count` variable is redundant. And the code is invalid - it verifies only the source word, so in case of ambiguous translations it will fail.

Comment: @BartoszKP Roger that... :)

Comment: The `while` loop can be replaced with: `for translation in iter(input, ''):`

Comment: Words: bandicoot = jarlku
Word: bandicoot = jarlku
Word: dog = jarntu
Word: dog = kuna-palya
Word: kangaroo = kanyarla
Word: cockatoo = ngaarnkamarda
Word: 
You know 5 unique word translation(s)!

Comment: @Ron it gives only 4 to me.

Comment: I just added a second example above, this code doesnt work for that one?

Comment: @Ron Just replace `source = translation.split()[0].strip()` line with `source = translation`, and it should work fine.(or better use a `set`)

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Thanks yaar. Learnt about `iter` :)

Answer (score 0):

1) Move the line with `input` to be the last statement of the loop.

2) In the if block, don't break out of the loop, add the new translation to `previous` list.

3) Print `len(previous)` at the end. The `count` variable is not needed.